# pyinstaller issue in building in windows 10 pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

stuck in this hole for last 3 days if I remember correctly. I am building a qt application on windows 10 pycharm, trying to create executable file by: pyinstaller --onefile gui.py

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1082]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

(venv) C:\sudip\projects\stockMarketDownload>pyinstaller --onefile gui.py
72 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.0
72 INFO: Python: 3.8.6
72 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
74 INFO: wrote C:\sudip\projects\stockMarketDownload\gui.spec
76 INFO: UPX is not available.
82 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\sudip\\projects\\stockMarketDownload',
 'C:\\sudip\\projects\\stockMarketDownload']
89 INFO: checking Analysis
152 INFO: checking PYZ
188 INFO: checking PKG
188 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
188 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\sudip\projects\stockMarketDownload\venv\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\sudip\projects\stockmarketdownload\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\sudip\projects\stockmarketdownload\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\sudip\projects\stockmarketdownload\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 720, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\sudip\projects\stockmarketdownload\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 667, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\sudip\projects\stockMarketDownload\gui.spec", line 20, in <module>
    exe = EXE(pyz,
  File "c:\sudip\projects\stockmarketdownload\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 434, in __init__
    self.pkg = PKG(self.toc, cdict=kwargs.get('cdict', None),
  File "c:\sudip\projects\stockmarketdownload\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 200, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\sudip\projects\stockmarketdownload\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\sudip\projects\stockmarketdownload\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 260, in assemble
    fnm = checkCache(fnm, strip=self.strip_binaries,
  File "c:\sudip\projects\stockmarketdownload\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 213, in checkCache
    digest = cacheDigest(fnm, redirects)
  File "c:\sudip\projects\stockmarketdownload\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 358, in cacheDigest
    with open(fnm, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''

(venv) C:\sudip\projects\stockMarketDownload>
```

Anybody, encountered and could fix this? will be really helpful.

Thanks and Regards,
Sudip

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether the following will solve it or not.

But, try adding upx.exe directory in your PATH variable in your PC.

Also, add designer.exe directory too.
(C:\Users(your user name)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5-tools\designer.exe)

Comment: I added upx directory, installed pyqt-tools to get get designer.exe and gave like this way: 
pyinstaller.exe gui.py --upx-dir="C:\software\upx-3.96-win64" -p "C:\project1\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5_tools\Qt\bin" -y --onefile, but still the same error...is my way of providing parameter correct?